# Customize Print Dialog for windows desktop system users

Tags: dialog

Is there a way to customize the default Print Dialog on Windows Desktop, for all system users. This is not within the context of a specific application, but instead will be for all users that log in to the workstation and uses any application and issues a "Print".

As part of a Green initiative, our organization wants to reduce wastage of Print paper. So we want to display a YES/NO message box that says something similar to "Please consider if you really want to continue printing. Save paper...Save Environment. Continue?"

If the user clicks  "Yes" , then the Print Dialog display is resumed and user can continue. If user clicks "no", then no further action is needed and system does not display Print dialog.

Thanks